# Sorting an Array of Objects in Python using Specific Keys

Tags: python, arrays, json, date, nested

My Requirement is to go through all arrays of objects within a json and, if an array of objects contain the contain the field "StartDate", sort that particular array of objects from the object with the latest StartDate to the object with the earliest StartDate.

This is a snippet of how my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "PersonId": "0000000000000000",
            "PersonNumber": "0000000000",
            "CorrespondenceLanguage": null,
            "BloodType": null,
            "DateOfBirth": "1990-01-01",
            "DateOfDeath": null,
            "CountryOfBirth": null,
            "RegionOfBirth": null,
            "TownOfBirth": null,
            "ApplicantNumber": null,
            "CreatedBy": "CREATOR",
            "CreationDate": "2023-11-23T11:41:21.743000+00:00",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "CREATOR",
            "LastUpdateDate": "2023-12-01T21:36:38.694000+00:00",
            "workRelationships": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "PeriodOfServiceId": "0",
                        "LegislationCode": "US",
                        "LegalEntityId": "0",
                        "LegalEmployerName": "Employer LLC",
                        "WorkerType": "E",
                        "PrimaryFlag": true,
                        "StartDate": "2013-10-21",
                        "assignments": {
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "AssignmentId": 300000006167868,
                                    "AssignmentNumber": "A0000-0",
                                    "AssignmentName": "Project Manager",
                                    "ActionCode": "TERMINATION",
                                    "ReasonCode": "TEST",
                                    "EffectiveStartDate": "2022-12-22"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "PeriodOfServiceId": "0",
                        "LegislationCode": "US",
                        "LegalEntityId": "0",
                        "LegalEmployerName": "Employer LLC",
                        "WorkerType": "E",
                        "PrimaryFlag": true,
                        "StartDate": "2023-12-08",
                        "assignments": {
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "AssignmentId": 0,
                                    "AssignmentNumber": "A000000-0",
                                    "AssignmentName": "Project management B1",
                                    "ActionCode": "REHIRE",
                                    "ReasonCode": null,
                                    "EffectiveStartDate": "2023-12-08"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I already have a python code that I think should do the trick, but it seems to not be changing anything:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

def main(input):
  adata = json.loads(input['workerData'])
  output_data = sort_arrays_with_StartDate(adata)
  return {'items': output_data}

def sort_arrays_with_StartDate(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key == 'StartDate' and isinstance(value, list):
                data[key] = sorted(value, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.get('StartDate', ''), '%Y-%m-%d'), reverse=True)
            elif isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
                data[key] = sort_arrays_with_StartDate(value)  # Update the original data
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(data):
            data[i] = sort_arrays_with_StartDate(item)  # Update the original data
    return data  # Return the updated data
```

Using this code, you would think that the 2 items in WorkRelationship would be rearranged and flipped, but running the json through this does not seem to do anything.

Comment: In your JSON snippet, `StartDate` is a `string` not `list`

Answer (score 0):

`StartDate` isn't the key that contains the list you want to sort, it's a key in the nested object of the list.

```
def sort_arrays_with_StartDate(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0 and isinstance(value[0], dict) and 'StartDate' in value[0]:
                data[key] = sorted(value, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.get('StartDate', ''), '%Y-%m-%d'), reverse=True)
            elif isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
                data[key] = sort_arrays_with_StartDate(value)  # Update the original data
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(data):
            data[i] = sort_arrays_with_StartDate(item)  # Update the original data
    return data  # Return the updated data
```